# Slideshow c# html razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I need to make a slideshow, on a webpage.I am not allowed to use javascript, it must be coded using c# and html using the razor syntax. I have an array of images, my lecturer suggested using switch statements, but I have been trying for weeks with no avail. I have tried, form posts, if statements, switch statements. 
he will not give any more help with this.
this is my array and this is how I'm calling the variable, this works fine, however i cant figure out how to make it change when i click next or previous. I've removed all code from the buttons as nothing ive tried will work. 
any help would be greatly appreciated

```
string[] images = {"images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg", "images/4.jpg", "images/5.jpeg", "images/6.png", "images/7.png", "images/8.png"};



<img src="@image" width="250px" height="250px" /><br />
<button>Next</button>
<button>Previous</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make next and previous "buttons" be links that call a controller with the number of the next and previous page in the query string parameter

Answer (score 0):

You would of course ideally use JavaScript for this.

An alternative, and IMO not the best way, is to do something like:

```
<a href="?imageID=121">Previous</a>
<a href="?imageID=123">Next</a>
```

...and then get your razor template to display the appropriate image:

```
@{
  string imageID = Request.QueryString["imageID"];
  // fetch the image based on this ID 
  // (insert your logic here to get your image)
  string theImage = @fetch.your.image

  <img src="@theImage" />
}
```